# Declare pointer to pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to understand simple pointers a little better by clarifying for myself the address a pointer points to, the address of the pointer itself and the value the address refers to. So I wrote a small piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p;
    int **pp;

    a = 42;

    /* Take the address of a */
    p = &a;

    /* Take the address of p */
    pp = &p;

    printf("Address of int &a:                          %p\n\n", &a);
    printf("value of a:                                 %d\n\n", a);

    printf("Address where *p points to via (void *)p:   %p\n\n", (void *)p);
    printf("Value that *p points to via *p:             %d\n\n", *p);
    printf("Address of *p itself via (void *)&p:        %p\n\n", (void *)&p);

    printf("Address where **p points to via (void *)pp: %p\n\n", (void *)pp);
    printf("Value that **pp points to via **pp:         %d\n\n", **pp);
    printf("Address of **p itself via (void *)&pp:      %p\n\n", (void *)&pp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This all works as expected (Please, do correct me if I made any mistakes here.). Now, I want to go one level deeper and use a pointer to a pointer to pointer `***ppp` and assign it the address the pointer to pointer `pp` points to which is the address `*p` points to which is the address of `a`. Here is how I thought I could do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p;
    int **pp;
    int **ppp;

    a = 42;

    /* Take the address of a */
    p = &a;

    /* Take the address of p */
    pp = &p;

    ppp = &pp;

    printf("Address of int &a:                               %p\n\n", &a);
    printf("value of a:                                      %d\n\n", a);

    printf("Address where *p points to via (void *)p:        %p\n\n", (void *)p);
    printf("Value that *p points to via *p:                  %d\n\n", *p);
    printf("Address of *p itself via (void *)&p:             %p\n\n", (void *)&p);

    printf("Address where **pp points to via (void *)pp:     %p\n\n", (void *)pp);
    printf("Value that **pp points to via **pp:              %d\n\n", **pp);
    printf("Address of **pp itself via (void *)&pp:          %p\n\n", (void *)&pp);

    printf("Address where ***ppp points to via (void *)ppp:  %p\n\n", (void *)ppp); 
    printf("Value that ***ppp points to via ***ppp:          %d\n\n", ***ppp);
    printf("Address where ***ppp points to via (void *)&ppp: %p\n\n", (void *)&ppp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this gives me an incompatible pointer warning. Could someone explain to me why this does not work and if the calls to `printf()` are right?

Comment: What is the exact warning you get, and what line is it on?

Comment: `int **ppp;` should be `int ***ppp;`. Also, `(void **)*ppp` is incorrect. It should be `(void *)*ppp` .

Comment: Da**it. Should I leave it for future reference or rather delete the question?

Comment: Terminology: "Address where *X points to" should be "Address of where X points to". The pointer points to the location; `*X` designates the location, not the address

Comment: @brauner voting to close as "typo"

Comment: Cheers @MattMcNabb, voted so myself.

Comment: Before it goes away, are the `printf()` statements correct to print the address of the pointer itself etc.?

Comment: @brauner I think so.. you should be able to tell pretty quickly based on whether the output makes sense

Answer (score 3):

The error is in this line
int **ppp; /* It should be ***ppp, because you're pointing to a pointer which points to another one*/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
int **ppp;
```

That should be

```
int ***ppp;
```

As it is now your trying to force a triple pointer, into a double pointer. Which will probably gives you an error on this line:

```
ppp = &pp;
```

**Also** you might want to have a look at number 2 of [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/19/c-undefined-behaviors/):).

**P.s.**
For future reference, if you provide a line number and specific error. People might want to help you even better and more:)